# App Engine Connected Android Project Error

Tags: android, google-app-engine, gwt

Setup:
Windows7, Eclipse 3.7.1,

Steps:
1. read and done all the tutorial in AppEngine connected android page (google)

1. copy all the files from http://code.google.com/p/cloud-tasks-io/source/browse/ with minor changes (my app-id wherever needed, my c2dm email..
2. deploy to app-engine.
3. test the GWT side: login succeed, add tasks works (I can see that tasks are added in the Google dashboard).
4. For testing the android side I'm debug as "Remote app engine Connected ..."
5. In the my android device (Sunsung Galaxy II, 2.3.5) I pressed Menu --> Accounts --> Connect (to my email account - same as above).
6. I'm getting notification : "Registered my_mail@gmail.com for.."
7. I pressed Menu --> refresh and get the following exception (logcat):

   02-13 00:55:09.015: E/AndroidRuntime(25572): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
       02-13 00:55:09.015: E/AndroidRuntime(25572): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
       02-13 00:55:09.015: E/AndroidRuntime(25572):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
       02-13 00:55:09.015: E/AndroidRuntime(25572):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
       02-13 00:55:09.015: E/AndroidRuntime(25572):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
       02-13 00:55:09.015: E/AndroidRuntime(25572):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
       02-13 00:55:09.015: E/AndroidRuntime(25572):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
       02-13 00:55:09.015: E/AndroidRuntime(25572):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
       02-13 00:55:09.015: E/AndroidRuntime(25572):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
       02-13 00:55:09.015: E/AndroidRuntime(25572):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
       02-13 00:55:09.015: E/AndroidRuntime(25572): Caused by: com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.UmbrellaException: One or more exceptions caught, see full set in UmbrellaException#getCauses
       02-13 00:55:09.015: E/AndroidRuntime(25572):    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.AbstractRequestContext$StandardPayloadDialect.processPayload(AbstractRequestContext.java:387)
       02-13 00:55:09.015: E/AndroidRuntime(25572):    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.AbstractRequestContext$5.onTransportSuccess(AbstractRequestContext.java:1108)
       02-13 00:55:09.015: E/AndroidRuntime(25572):    at com.cloudtasks.AndroidRequestTransport.send(AndroidRequestTransport.java:68)
       02-13 00:55:09.015: E/AndroidRuntime(25572):    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.AbstractRequestContext.doFire(AbstractRequestContext.java:1102)
       02-13 00:55:09.015: E/AndroidRuntime(25572):    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.AbstractRequestContext.fire(AbstractRequestContext.java:569)
       02-13 00:55:09.015: E/AndroidRuntime(25572):    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.AbstractRequest.fire(AbstractRequest.java:54)
       02-13 00:55:09.015: E/AndroidRuntime(25572):    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.AbstractRequest.fire(AbstractRequest.java:59)
       02-13 00:55:09.015: E/AndroidRuntime(25572):    at com.cloudtasks.AsyncFetchTask.doInBackground(AsyncFetchTask.java:31)
       02-13 00:55:09.015: E/AndroidRuntime(25572):    at com.cloudtasks.AsyncFetchTask.doInBackground(AsyncFetchTask.java:1)
       02-13 00:55:09.015: E/AndroidRuntime(25572):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
       02-13 00:55:09.015: E/AndroidRuntime(25572):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
       02-13 00:55:09.015: E/AndroidRuntime(25572):    ... 4 more
       02-13 00:55:09.015: E/AndroidRuntime(25572): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Server Error: null
       02-13 00:55:09.015: E/AndroidRuntime(25572):    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.Receiver.onFailure(Receiver.java:44)
       02-13 00:55:09.015: E/AndroidRuntime(25572):    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.AbstractRequest.onFail(AbstractRequest.java:118)
       02-13 00:55:09.015: E/AndroidRuntime(25572):    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.AbstractRequestContext$StandardPayloadDialect.processPayload(AbstractRequestContext.java:359)
       02-13 00:55:09.015: E/AndroidRuntime(25572):    ... 14 more
8. when I try to run again, same process, except pressing Menu --> refresh I tried to add new task. This time I didn't see any exception in logcat but I see in Eclipse (see attached pic in [original question](http://code.google.com/p/cloud-tasks-io/issues/detail?id=8&thanks=8&ts=1329087868)): source not found - ThreadPoolExecutor.java

PLEASE HELP ME!

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issues playing with this tutorial. I think after they posted the code a change was made to the RPC Service in the Google Plugin because now it no longer creates a class called CloudTasksRequestFactory.java, instead it has a class CloudTasksRequest.java. Also, these two classes are very different:

CloudTasksRequestFactory.java

```
package com.cloudtasks.shared;

import com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.RequestFactory;


public interface CloudTasksRequestFactory extends RequestFactory {

    TaskRequest taskRequest();

}
```

CloudTasksRequest.java

package com.cloudtasks.shared;

```
import java.util.List;

import com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.Request;
import com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.RequestContext;
import com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.ServiceName;

@ServiceName(value = "com.cloudtasks.server.CloudTasksService", locator = "com.cloudtasks.server.CloudTasksServiceLocator")
public interface CloudTasksRequest extends RequestContext {

    Request<TaskProxy> createTask();

    Request<TaskProxy> readTask(Long id);

    Request<TaskProxy> updateTask(TaskProxy task);

    Request<Void> deleteTask(TaskProxy task);

    Request<List<TaskProxy>> queryTasks();

}
```

This leads me to believe that there was some architecture or logic changed that prevents the tutorial being correctly built with the updated tools. You might want to look at https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/appeng_android_add_rpc which seems to be more up to date in the instructions.